# How to Get the Handle of all Windows in a process using process ID

Tags: windows, winapi, process, vbscript, handle

I wanted to know is there any way to retrieve all the handles associated with a process using process ID in VBScript ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I dont know about VBScript, but the WinAPI Functions to use would be

1. [Thread32First](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686728%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)/[Thread32Next](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686731%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in order to iterate over all
       threads line in [this (c++) sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686852%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
2. [EnumThreadWindows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)